# what track and track length means in SFM

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, structure-from-motion

when I read the paper "Structure-from-Motion Revisited". 
I met a few words I didn't understand，　 "track" and "track length".
what exactly these terms mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A track is a sequence of image positions of a feature (usually an image point) in subsequent images. For example, the track of an eye in a video showing a person is the sequences of pixel positions of that eye in the video stream

Track length is the number of frames that feature is successfully tracked for - say, from the frame the feature is detected to the one it is lost, e.g. due to occlusion, blurring, going out of the field of view or very far away, etc.